# Populating a XAML Store App combobox from a Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq, xaml, combobox, windows-store-apps

Hopefully this will be an easy one. Something I have overlooked.

I am attempting to populating a combobox in a Store App from a Linq query. This not a two way relationship. the values of the CB will be used to change other display elements for reporting purposes - it's read only.

Linq returns an iEnumerable list of . I am assigning this to the .DataContext of the CB in C#

```
public MyClass
{
    public string Area;
}

this.AreaList.DataContext = QueryData;
this.AreaList.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

I know the data has been "attached" as I can programmatically get to it:

```
MyClass item = (MyClass)this.AreaList.SelectedItem;
MyOtherClass.Area = item.Area;
```

This issue is that the CB shows the right number of values in it, but they are all blank. I've tried numerous XAML combinations but none offer anything to the screen.

The current non-working XAML is:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="AreaList" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="Area" SelectedValuePath="Area" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

Any help to get my Area attribute displayed in the CB would be much appreciated.

Cheers,

Roy

Answer (score 0):

I am considering `QueryData` is `List<MyClass>` then `Area` should be a property rather than field (variable) if you want to bind `ComboBox` with `List<T>`. I would recommend to use `List<string>` then no need to use `DisplayMemberPath` & `SelectedValuePath`. So you just need to remove `DisplayMemberPath` & `SelectedValuePath` if you go for `List<string>` and then use

```
MyOtherClass.Area = AreaList.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Comment: As mentioned in the original post. It is an IEnumerable <MyClass>. I also don't see how SelectedItem.ToString() will help as I've already stated I can access the info in all circumstances. I just can't get the combobox to display the .Area attribute value within the combobox.

Comment: Why you are using `IEnumerable<MyClass>`, `MyClass` is having only single property that's also string, so you should go with `IEnumerable<string>`

Comment: I could, but what I didn't want to go in to is all the code that sits behind this. I have a standard pattern that returns data in a standard structured.

In this instance MyClass has one attribute. Other Linq queries return more. MyClass inherits from BaseClass which enables me to string type my other methods and properties.

Answer (score 0):

Use

**this.AreaList.ItemsSource = QueryData;**

instead of

**this.AreaList.DataContext = QueryData;**

Comment: Tried that. ..  same result

Answer (score 0):

So my issue was getting the custom object to populate the combobox. I tried every combination of XAML attributes trying to work with the IEnumerable<> returned by Linq.

After much deliberation, the easiest solution was to take the IEnumerable<> and simply extract the attribute I wanted to a List.

The end result was to use the .Select() method.

```
public List<string> Filter()
{
    var data = from c in this.Source.XDoc.Descendants("R")
        group c by c.Element("C0").Value into d
        select new { d.Key };

    return data.Select(area => area.Key).ToList();
}
```

Seems obvious now.

Cheers,

Roy